# Shared memory in C with LinkedList

Tags: c, linked-list, shared-memory

I have to develop a mini-shell in C. In this project we have to deal with local variables and environment variables. So we can have two process that shared environment variables, a variable create in the child can be seen in the father and inversely.

My teacher says: 
**The environment variables are stored in a shared memory area that is created by the first copy of your shell that runs and is initialized with all the variables defined in the envp array. The last copy of your shell that runs at any given time must destroy that space. This shared memory area is to be managed as a memory by subdivision. The shared memory area is a concurrent access memory area with multiple possible simultaneous reads but only 1 write possible at a given time. Implementation must give priority to writing.**

So we need shared memory with linked list who contains:

- the name of variable (char*)
- the int return by shmget()
- and a char* return by shmat(), the value of variable

But when we create a environment variable in the father there is not in the child.

So I think this method is not correct, how can we represents this problem ?

Maybe not use a linked list ?

Thank you.

TF.

Comment: why shared memory? environment variables already share between parent and child process.

Comment: you should know first how command executes on shell. i believe you have to use exec() system call for it.

Comment: So you want Inter Process Communication. Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication has a fair list of options

Comment: The shared memory is an obligation because I must create the job of a shell. So I copy the value of envp in my memory shared and I want shared this. I create a new environment variable with internal command setenv (setenv foo=bar). It's a project for my university so I can't use the putenv function for environment variable. But my setenv==putenv for my shell.

Comment: "shared environment variables" i suggest you double check this. this sounds very similar to, but at the same time different from, how real environment variables behave. as you have stated the task, it is orders of magnitude harder than a simple shell that just uses normal plain environment variables. it would be a shame if you wasted lots of efforts to implement these almost-environment-variables when your teachers meant simple honest real environment variables, and you just misunderstood them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My theacher says:  "The environment variables are stored in a shared memory area that is created by the first copy of your shell that runs and is initialized with all the variables defined in the envp array. The last copy of your shell that runs at any given time must destroy that space. This shared memory area is to be managed as a memory by subdivision. The shared memory area is a concurrent access memory area with multiple possible simultaneous reads but only 1 write possible at a given time. Implementation must give priority to writing." Thank you again.

Comment: Your teacher is asking you to create (1) a thing that doesn't exist anywhere in the world (because it would be) (2) a totally useless "feature" and (3) a major security hole. Just so you know. It could be an interesting exercise though. You need to post his explanation in the body of the question and highlight it, to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @n.m. those points are not really not relevant in an *exercise*.

Comment: @el.pescado Perhaps they are not, but it's still useful to know about them, which is why I comment about such things,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my question. So I don't know how create this functionnality ?

Comment: I don't get the point of using environment variables. If you are to use shared memory to store information for inter process communication, why call them environment variables? Just say i want to exchange data via shared memory. How do i do that? Why even mention environment variables in the first place?

Comment: Shared memory is not preserved across `exec`. Instances of your shell should explicitly attach a pre-agreed shared memory segment. It makes no sense to have a segment per variable. You need just one segment where all variables are stored. Non-shell executables started by the shell have no idea about your shared memory segment, you neet to prepare a conventional envp for child processes. I don't quite understand what linked lists have to do with all this.

Comment: @k_kaz I say "environment variable" because the goal of project is to create a shell and I must simulate the job of a shell. It's not really environment variable. And I have the local variable in my shell who are different and not shared.  The linked list is my proposition not the solution imposed. I'm open of other solutions.

Comment: But I don't know the size of segment so it is the reason why I have create 1 segment per variable. But maybe it's possible to "realloc" the size of the segment for create a undefined number of variable.

Comment: Maximal size of the environment is normally limited by the OS.

Comment: Yes but my segment contains envp variable + the personnal variable create in my shell with my internal command setenv. So i can have size of envp + a lot of variables more. I don't know in advance the size of this segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand ! 
My teacher say me to create a shared memory space with fixed size ! It's simple now.

Thank you everyone.